# Display current time from timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a **timer** which counts from o to 100 and display it in **ptag** with id **countdowntimer**

Im trying to display the **current time** when i click a button from the timer running.

also i want to **reset** the timer **after button** click.

how do i achieve it?

```js
var timeleft = 1;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft++;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft >= 100)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    },1000);
    
    
    
    function timenow()
{
var timenow=document.getElementById("timetaken").textContent = timeleft;

}
```

```html
<p> Time   <span id="countdowntimer">0 </span></p>
<p> Time  Taken  <span id="timetaken">0 </span></p>
<button onclick="timenow">Click to viw time taken</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick function event is not bind correctly. To reset timer just reset `timeleft` var in button click function to 0

```js
var timeleft = 1;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft++;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft >= 100)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    },1000);
    
    
    
    function timenow()
{
  document.getElementById("timetaken").textContent = timeleft;
  timeleft=0;
  document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
}
```

```html
<p> Time   <span id="countdowntimer">0 </span></p>
<p> Time  Taken  <span id="timetaken">0 </span></p>
<button onclick="timenow()">Click to viw time taken</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should fire the function in onclick event, secondly you should reset timelefet value in that function.

Your code should look something like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p> Time <span id="countdowntimer">0 </span></p>
    <p> Time Taken <span id="timetaken">0 </span></p>
    <button onclick="timenow()">Click to viw time taken</button> <!-- changed timenow to timenow() -->

    <script>
        var sum = 0;
        var timeleft = 1;
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
            timeleft++;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
            if (timeleft >= 100)
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        }, 1000);



        function timenow() {
            sum += timeleft;
            var timenow = document.getElementById("timetaken").textContent = sum;
            timeleft = 0;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
        }   
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is displaying for me, but if you need time taken to be the sum of all you should change the code a little bit

Comment: Works fine rechecked,  Thanks for reply

Comment: I added sum variable, if this was what you needed, check it out